# Android Studio not see plugin generated class and res, how can i solve?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-safe-args

Android studio (2022.3.1 Patch 2) not seen files generated by plugins in this folders:

- generated/res/processDebugGoogleServices
- generated/source/navigation-args

But Gradle works fine and app works perfectly, i just have error indication in IDE and no suggestion. Generated BuildConfig and ViewBinding works. Already tried to invalidate cache or remove folder .gradle and .idea. my conf are:

root build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.2" apply false
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.0" apply false
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin") version "2.7.4" apply false
}
```

module build.gradle.kts:

```
compileSdk = 34

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JvmTarget.JVM_11.target
}

buildFeatures {
    buildConfig = true
    viewBinding = true
}
```

Comment: I find things like this usually happen when the java sdk i'm using has changed. Sync, invalidate and rebuild usually sorts it out though.